# Converting date set in 'DDMMYYYY'd format in Teradata

Tags: sql, date, teradata

I have an existing SAS program that reads in various macro date variables, and I am using these variables as one of my parameters in running queries in Teradata.

One of the macro variables is formatted as `DDMMYYYY`, and I want to convert this to a format that can be read in Teradata; I tried the following query but it doesn't seem to work, can someone point out what's wrong?

```
ME_DT (Teradata date variable) = CAST(CAST(&QEOP AS DATE FORMAT 'DDMMYYYY'd) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

where &QEOP is a macro date variable.

Comment: What does the macro variable contain? Why do you have two CAST() functions?  Why do you have lowercase d after the format string for the inner CAST() function? What error messages are you getting from Teradata?

Answer (score 1):

Teradata wants single quotes around strings. Double quotes are used around object names.  Normally you can just use date literals in the form

```
'2017-05-01'
```

So if you have a SAS date value in a macro variable:

```
%let mydate="01MAY2017"d ;
```

You can generate the value using combination of PUTN() function and some macro quoting. It is best to remove the macro quoting.

```
%let tddate=%unquote(%bquote('%sysfunc(putn(&mydate,yymmdd10))'));
```

Then your Teradata code could be as simple as this to compare to an existing date variable.

```
where ME_DT = &tddate
```

or if you want to make sure it knows you meant a date and not a string literal add the DATE keyword.

```
values (DATE &tddate)
```